# On tagging "Command & Conquer"

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a single [command-and-conquer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer), which has 8 questions distributed thusly among actual games in the series.

- *Command & Conquer: Generals* - [1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/611/how-do-i-increase-the-camera-height-in-command-conquer-generals) [2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/how-can-i-run-cc-generals-zero-hour-on-windows-7) [3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6451/in-command-and-conquer-generals-zero-hour-what-tactics-can-i-use-for-china-infa)
- *Command & Conquer: Generals - Zero Hour* - [1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/611/how-do-i-increase-the-camera-height-in-command-conquer-generals) [2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/how-can-i-run-cc-generals-zero-hour-on-windows-7) [3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6451/in-command-and-conquer-generals-zero-hour-what-tactics-can-i-use-for-china-infa) (These are the same 3 as the above, actually, I'm not sure if they do or do not apply to both)
- *Command & Conquer: Gold* - [1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10353/running-command-conquer-gold-on-windows-7-64-bit-in-xp-mode)
- *Command & Conquer: Tiberian Sun* - [1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10589/command-conquer-tiberian-sun-on-windows-7)
- *Command & Conquer 4* - [1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12522/cc4-says-i-need-more-command-posts-points)
- *Command & Conquer: Red Alert* - [1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12791/downloadable-useable-red-alert-2-audio-clips) [2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12927/detailed-instructions-for-iphone-version-of-cc-red-alert)
- *Command & Conquer 3* - [1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17434/if-i-have-multiple-bases-which-one-will-produce-units) (This one was already retagged to [command-and-conquer-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-3))

Well, it's a mess. There is also one [red-alert](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-alert), as well as [cnc-zero-hour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc-zero-hour) applied twice and [cnc-generals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc-generals) applied once. Certainly, dividing it won't directly help us. So thought patterns go...

1. Can we clean this up a bit, and how best to do it? Do we split up the expansions, and how so?
2. Is "CNC" intuitive enough for this series? Consider that on RPG, they used to have [dnd] to handle D&D, but that was eventually nixed in favor of [dd]. If it isn't, what is the best way to handle those 26+ character titles?

Comment: These long name many version tags are a real problem in general.  See [RPG's long history of wrangling with the D&D tag set](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags).

Answer (score 3):

I think in this specific case, our best bet is to rely on multiple tags.

[command-and-conquer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer) for all titles belonging to the series, and then additionally the specific game i.e. [red-alert](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-alert), or, for disambiguation purposes if the title is sufficiently vague or numerical, [cnc-generals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc-generals)