# Rename Command & Conquer tags, thanks to the 35 character limit

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

*[Command & Conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_%26_Conquer)* is a prolific video game series that of course we have questions for on this site. Now that we have a 35 character limit for tags, I think the tagging for those questions needs to be revisited.

[The last time tagging was discussed](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1862/47878), there were concerns about the 25 character tag limit. The consensus at the time was to get around this limit by having [command-and-conquer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer) be a tag that all games in the series, then tagging specific games with the latter part of the name. For instance, a question about *Command & Conquer: Red Alert* would be tagged with both [command-and-conquer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer) and [red-alert](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-alert).

In practice, this hasn't worked out. The tag wiki for [command-and-conquer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer) talks exclusively about the original 1995 video game. Some questions are about that game and some are about other games in the series; it's kind of messy.

### Proposal going forward

- [command-and-conquer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer) (only to be used for [the 1995 game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_%26_Conquer_(1995_video_game)))
- [tiberian-sun](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiberian-sun) → [command-and-conquer-tiberian-sun](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-tiberian-sun)
- [command-and-conquer-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-3) → [command-and-conquer-3-tiberium-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-3-tiberium-wars)
- [red-alert](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-alert) → [command-and-conquer-red-alert](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-red-alert)
- [red-alert-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-alert-2) → [command-and-conquer-red-alert-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-red-alert-2)
- [red-alert-2-yuris-revenge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-alert-2-yuris-revenge) → [command-and-conquer-yuris-revenge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-yuris-revenge) (this is [the name Wikipedia calls the expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_%26_Conquer:_Yuri%27s_Revenge))
- [red-alert-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-alert-3) → [command-and-conquer-red-alert-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-red-alert-3)
- [generals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generals) → [command-and-conquer-generals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-generals)

In all of these cases except maybe [generals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generals), keeping the old tag as a synonym makes sense.

<sub>Sadly, Stack Exchange does not allow `&` in tags.</sub>

### Unfortunately, there are three games that exceed the 35 character limit

- *[Command & Conquer 4: Tiberian Twilight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_%26_Conquer_4:_Tiberian_Twilight)*

  - Current tag: [command-and-conquer-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-4)
  - Full tag: [command-and-conquer-4-tiberian-twilight](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-4-tiberian-twilight) (39 characters)
  - Suggestion: Leave as [command-and-conquer-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-4)
- *[Command & Conquer: Generals – Zero Hour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_%26_Conquer:_Generals_%E2%80%93_Zero_Hour)*

  - Current tag: [cnc-zero-hour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc-zero-hour)
  - Full tag: [command-and-conquer-generals-zero-hour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-generals-zero-hour) (38 characters)
  - Suggestion: Retag to [command-and-conquer-zero-hour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-zero-hour)
- *[Command & Conquer: Tiberium Alliances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_%26_Conquer:_Tiberium_Alliances)*

  - Current tag: [tiberium-alliances](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiberium-alliances)
  - Full tag: [command-and-conquer-tiberium-alliances](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-tiberium-alliances) (38 characters)
  - Suggestion: ????

I'd be open to discussion about any of these, especially what to do about *Command & Conquer: Tiberium Alliances*.

Comment: For the longer ones, would taking out the word "and" make enough difference?

Comment: @Ash Yes, we would be under 35 characters with, for instance, `command-conquer-tiberium-alliances`. I'm concerned that that may lead to confusion though, since "Command & Conquer" is so firmly linked to the brand name. If someone starts typing in `command-and-conquer`, they won't find a tag for the game they're seeking.

Comment: Well, it should come up at "command", no?

Comment: @Ash True, it would, although for me I'd keep tying to "and" because I'm a fast typer, and then would lose it. I'd prefer the common abbreviation `cnc` rather than `command-conquer` (as used in [cnc.wikia.com](http://cnc.wikia.com/wiki/EVA_Database)), but of course, that doesn't really solve the problem. I guess if we have to remove "and", we could, but I wish there was a better way.

Comment: @Ash The tag suggestion box only displays the top 6 matching tags. Tying `command` would show the other C&C games before showing `tiberium-alliances`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have conquered these tags:

- [cnc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc) → [command-and-conquer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer)
- [cnc-tiberian-sun](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc-tiberian-sun) → [command-and-conquer-tiberian-sun](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-tiberian-sun)
- [cnc-3-tiberium-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc-3-tiberium-wars) → [command-and-conquer-3-tiberium-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-3-tiberium-wars)
- [cnc-generals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc-generals) → [command-and-conquer-generals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-generals)
- [cnc-red-alert](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc-red-alert) → [command-and-conquer-red-alert](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-red-alert)
- [cnc-red-alert-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc-red-alert-2) → [command-and-conquer-red-alert-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-red-alert-2)
- [cnc-red-alert-2-yuris-revenge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc-red-alert-2-yuris-revenge) → [command-and-conquer-yuris-revenge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-yuris-revenge)
- [cnc-red-alert-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc-red-alert-3) → [command-and-conquer-red-alert-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-red-alert-3)
- [cnc-4-tiberian-twilight](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc-4-tiberian-twilight) → [command-and-conquer-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-4)
- [cnc-zero-hour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc-zero-hour) → [command-and-conquer-zero-hour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-zero-hour)
- [cnc-tiberium-alliances](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc-tiberium-alliances), [command-and-conquer-tiberium-a](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-tiberium-a) → [command-conquer-tiberium-alliances](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-conquer-tiberium-alliances)

I removed some of the original tag synonyms like 'generals' and replaced them with ones prefixed with the common community 'cnc' abbreviation, for consistency and ease of searching.

I went with [command-conquer-tiberium-alliances](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-conquer-tiberium-alliances) for the last tag, and added the "[command-and-conquer-tiberium-a](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-tiberium-a)" synonym. This, along with the 'cnc' tag should be enough that people can still find the tag easily.

Comment: Thank you for taking command of the situation!